# Detect when all flows produced value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I''m having two functions which upload some data to database.

```
suspend fun addOverallRatingValue(productId: String): Flow<FirebaseEventResponse>
suspend fun markProductAsRatedByUser(productId: String): Flow<FirebaseEventResponse>
```

Both of them are `callbackFlow`

```
override suspend fun markProductAsRatedByUser(productId: String) = callbackFlow {
        try {
            firebaseInstance
                ...
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    trySend(FirebaseEventResponse.SuccessSetValue)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    trySend(FirebaseEventResponse.ExceptionOccurred.Event(it))
                }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            trySend(FirebaseEventResponse.ExceptionOccurred.Event(e))
        }
        awaitClose { this.cancel() }
    }
```

How can I combine these two flows and react when both of them send any `FirebaseEventResponse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [`combine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) and [`zip`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html) functions you can use to combine flows:

```
combine(
    flow1,
    flow2,
) { result1, result2 ->
    // ... check results
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

The difference between them is that `combine` fires when the most recent value is emitted by each flow, and `zip` fires when each pair of value is emitted. Here is a good [article about `Flow` operators](https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-how-to-combine-kotlin-flows-317849a71d3e).

There is also [`merge`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html) function which merges the given flows into a single flow without preserving an order of elements:

```
merge(flow1, flow2).onEach { result ->
    // ... use result
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```